# How to get the value dynamically from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to retrieve a JSON value dynamically from JSON object. Below is the code i am using to get the value from JSON object.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(jsonObj);
jsonSplit = jsonToFind.split(htmlSplit+".")[1].trim();
console.log(jsonObj+"."+jsonSplit);
```

But  I am getting **[object Object].ensighten_tag**.
Here **ensighten_tag** is the dynamic key value.

Can anyone suggest me how to get the value dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(JsonObj[jsonSplit])
```

Comment: I am getting JsonObj and jsonSplit values, dynamically. I tried with your answer.

Comment: The code above works assuming the key exists in jsonObj

Comment: Can you post your output?